# Deny other than the specified UserAgent

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Help me figure out how to configure `apache` to the settings I need?

**domain.zone.conf** (what to write here?)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.zone
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sub.domain.zone
    ServerAlias sub.domain.zone
    ErrorLog /var/www/sub.domain.zone/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/sub.domain.zone/requests.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

You need to make it so that you can go to the subdomain of the site, with the specified `UserAgent`.

Tried to do like this:

**.htaccess**

```
# Encoding
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
# IndexPage
DirectoryIndex index.php
# CloseDirectories
Options All -Indexes
# Control UserAgent
<If "%{HTTP_USER_AGENT} != 'MYUSERAGENT'">
    Require all denied
</If>
```

Nothing works, I can still log in from any agent.
Tell me how to close access to everyone except the agent I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the rewriting module instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^MYUSERAGENT$
RewriteRule ^ - [R=403,L]
```

This rejects any request that does *not* specify the exact user agent header "MYUSERAGENT" and returns a http status 403 ("Forbidden").

If you want to match only a part of the user agent header, then just slightly change the condition:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !MYUSERAGENT
RewriteRule ^ - [R=403,L]
```

Comment: Removed `.htaccess`, in `domain.zone.conf` added to `VirtualHost` what you wrote and everything worked as it should! Fire!

Comment: Great to hear that. And indeed one should nearly always prefer to central host configuration over distributed configuration files (".htaccess"). Congratulations!

Comment: Doesn't work with `.htaccess`. I did not write about it, because it worked in `.conf`.

Comment: Maybe you did not enable the interpretation of those files. But anyway, the central configuration is more effective an more robust anyway.

Comment: No, the main thing is, only it does not work through `.htaccess`, and all other rules work correctly, I checked, page routing, cnc, works, redirects work, but the ban on the entire site does not work. Anyway.

Comment: There is no reason for that I can see in the actual rules visible here. So the issue has to be rooted somewhere else. If the same rules work in the cerntral configuration then there are most likely rules getting applied _before_ that rule gets considered when being implemented in a distributed configuration file.